# Adding a new column based on values of another column in Pandas(python)

Tags: python, pandas

Given a dataframe that looks something like

```
Vote A Vote B
   1     4      
   3     2      
   1     5
```

I want to add a new column named `Winner` that compares the value between two columns `Vote A` and `Vote B` and specify the winner.

```
Winner
B
A
B
```

How can I do this in Pandas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use

```
def winner(row):
    if row['Vote A'] > row['Vote B']:
        return 'A'
    elif row['Vote A'] < row['Vote B']:
        return 'B'
    else:
        return ''

df['Winner'] = df[['Vote A','Vote B']].apply(winner, axis=1)
```

Which yields

```
Vote A  Vote B  Winner
1       4       B
3       2       A
1       5       B
```

Comment: Thanks! This answer is the most flexible.

Answer (score 2):

Use `idxmax` and `.str`

```
In [274]: df['Winner'] = df[['Vote A','Vote B']].idxmax(axis=1).str[-1]

In [275]: df
Out[275]:
   Vote A  Vote B Winner
0       1       4      B
1       3       2      A
2       1       5      B
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df.eq(df.max(1),0).dot(df.columns).str[-1]
Out[223]: 
0    B
1    A
2    B
dtype: object
```

After assign it back

```
df.assign(New=df.eq(df.max(1),0).dot(df.columns).str[-1])
Out[224]: 
   VoteA  VoteB New
0      1      4   B
1      3      2   A
2      1      5   B
```